# Firefox video interruptions

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon, video-streaming

A website that I watch videos on has some sort of afk feature where it pauses the video and displays this message: "Are You Still There? Click To Continue Watching"

Is there a way I can make something automatically click on the click to continue? I was thinking of making an extension that 
1. searches for that text
2. clicks continue

Are there anyother/better ways to approach this?

Answer (score 0):

Is the message coming from Firefox of the website? You could use a simple [auto mouse mover](https://www.sobolsoft.com/automousemove/) type utility to either randomly move the mouse or to actually click on the continue button.

For Ubuntu, you can potentially use something like [xdotool](http://www.semicomplete.com/projects/xdotool/xdotool.xhtml). I haven't used this one before though.

Comment: its from the website i should have mentioned that sorry. thats a great tool but im on linux (ubuntu) so i cant use that tool specially but im sure there are alternatives. im looking for a fully automatic one that works on trigger